# Remove spaces from right and left (TRIM) all selected columns

Tags: sql, actian

I have went through some documentations and as it states `SELECT TRIM('') FROM something;` can be used to trim strings.

I have SQL command to get the table:

```
"select NRO,SNAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTS,POSTN,POSTTP,COMPANY,COUNTRY,BID from COMPANY where ACTIVE = '1' AND NRO Like '7%'"
```

So I have tried to use:

```
"select TRIM(NRO),TRIM(SNAME),TRIM(NAMEA),TRIM(NAMEB),TRIM(ADDRESS),TRIM(POSTS),TRIM(POSTN),TRIM(POSTTP),TRIM(COMPANY),TRIM(COUNTRY),TRIM(BID) from COMPANY where ACTIVE = '1' AND NRO Like '7%'"
```

but this is throwing an error. What is the proper way of using TRIM in this case? 
I need to remove spaces from left and right but leave them in between if there are any.

Error message:

> Client Interface][LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Error in expression: TRIM (
>   NRO )  ERROR [HY000] [PSQL][ODBC Client Interface][LNA][PSQL][SQL
>   Engine][Data Record Manager]Invalid user-defined or scalar function.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **LTRIM** and **RTRIM** functions which removes starting and ending spaces for the SQL Server prior to 2017.

So, your query becomes:

```
 select RTRIM(LTRIM(NRO)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SNAME),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(NAMEA)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(NAMEB)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ADDRESS)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTS)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTN)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTTP)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COMPANY)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COUNTRY)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(BID))
from COMPANY where ACTIVE = '1' AND NRO Like '7%'
```

For the SQL Server 2017 and later you can use [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function as Dale K suggested.

Comment: Seems that is newly added function, documentation says it applies to SQL Server 2017 and later versions.

Comment: Pretty sure OP is using MySQL anyway... (2017 is already 3 years ago :) )

Comment: Thank you for this! Now I don't receive any error but it looks like running forever. Still waiting for any data output to see the result.

Comment: @hatman it might be something related to your table's performance. How many records does it have in total? Try to test with less data like below:

select top 1 RTRIM(LTRIM(NRO)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(SNAME),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(NAMEA)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(NAMEB)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ADDRESS)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTS)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTN)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(POSTTP)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COMPANY)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(COUNTRY)),
    RTRIM(LTRIM(BID))
from COMPANY

Comment: You are using a `LIKE` statement for **NRO** column, it might be creating performance issue. Do you have any index on it?

Comment: For some reason even with `select top 1` it doesn't work. It just keeps going. After removing `RTRIM(LTRIM())` everything works. I can of course trim later in C# code, was just thinking maybe it can be done directly in SQL request. Also as already mentioned before `TRIM()` seems to be causing an errors.

Comment: I narrowed the query to one column only, try the below statement:
`select TOP 1 RTRIM(LTRIM(NRO))
from COMPANY WITH(NOLOCK)`